# Webpack 4 and foundation 6 work on watch, fail on build

Tags: webpack, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to make a starter project which will allow me to compile SCSS and minify JS.

I am using foundation framework 6.4.3 and webpack 4.11.1, you will see my config files here : https://github.com/jhabai/-ICE_starter_project

```
npm run dev 

npm run build

npm run proxy
```

all run without error, but on my main front page foundation doesn't manage to initialize

> typeError: e(...).foundation is not a function

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

after few changer on index.js it works ! https://github.com/jhabai/-ICE_starter_project